# EasyMock: How do I create a mock of a genericized class without a warning?

Tags: java, generics, mocking, easymock

The code

```
private SomeClass<Integer> someClass;
someClass = EasyMock.createMock(SomeClass.class);
```

gives me a warning "Type safety: The expression of type SomeClass needs unchecked conversion to conform to SomeClass<Integer>".

Answer (score 42):

AFAIK, you can't avoid the unchecked warning when a class name literal is involved, and the `SuppressWarnings` annotation is the only way to handle this.

Note that it is good form to narrow the scope of the `SuppressWarnings` annotation as much as possible. You can apply this annotation to a single local variable assignment:

```
public void testSomething() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Foo<Integer> foo = EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);

    // Rest of test method may still expose other warnings
}
```

or use a helper method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> Foo<T> createFooMock() {
    return (Foo<T>)EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);
}

public void testSomething() {
    Foo<String> foo = createFooMock();

    // Rest of test method may still expose other warnings
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I worked around this problem by introducing a subclass, e.g.

```
private abstract class MySpecialString implements MySpecial<String>{};
```

Then create a mock of that abstract class:

```
MySpecial<String> myMock = createControl().createMock(MySpecialString.class);
```

Comment: Additionally, don't forget to use the `org.easymock.classextension.EasyMock` version of EasyMock to create your mocks when using the abstract class.

Comment: As of EasyMock 3.0 (May 2010), the classes in `org.easymock.classextension` are deprecated and are simple proxies to the same-named classes in `org.easymock`. It is recommended to remove ".classextension" from your imports and stop compiling with the classextension library.

Answer (score 3):

The two obvious routes are to suppress the warning or mock a subclass.

```
private static class SomeClass_Integer extends SomeClass<Integer>();
private SomeClass<Integer> someClass;
...
    someClass = EasyMock.createMock(SomeClass_Integer.class);
```

(Disclaimer: Not even attempted to compile this code, nor have I used EasyMock.)

Comment: The syntax should probably be:

private static interface SomeClass_Integer extends SomeClass<Integer> {}

I have the same problem and this is the work around I use so the approach will work. But I hope somebody has the answer we are looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate the test method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. I agree this is some what of a hack but in my opinion it's acceptable on test code.

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void someTest() {
    SomeClass<Integer> someClass = EasyMock.createMock(SomeClass.class);
}
```

Comment: yeah, but that leaves me feeling cheap

Comment: If you go this route (hopefully there is a better way), much better to put the @SuppressWarnings on the variable assignment rather than the whole method.

Answer (score 1):

I know this goes against the question, but why not create a List rather than a Mock List?

It's less code and easier to work with, for instance if you want to add items to the list.

```
MyItem myItem = createMock(myItem.class);
List<MyItem> myItemList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
myItemList.add(myItem);
```

Instead of

```
MyItem myItem = createMock(myItem.class);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<MyItem> myItemList = createMock(ArrayList.class);
expect(myItemList.get(0)).andReturn(myItem);
replay(myItemList);
```